# Symfony to use base protocol as https instead of http in NGINX server

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'm having a application built in Symfony framework. The thing is application is mainly used for API of an Android app. Earlier it was hosted with Apache Webserver, but now it is shifted to Load Balancers and webserver is changed to Nginx, I've set rewrite rules accordingly and everything seems to be working fine till now expect one issue, that's protocol is http instead of https. I am attaching two screenshots, one of API response when application is with Apache Webserver and second when application is running with Nginx Webserver.

**When application is running with Apache WebServer:**

[image]

**When application is running with Nginx WebServer:**

[image]

You can see difference in protocols of image URL in JSON data.

We need to use it with https only. Is there anthing I'm missing, either maybe with Nginx or with application itself. There were no changes to application while migration related to this.

Maybe rewrite rules?

Comment: Have you tried to add `fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;` in nginx configuration?

Comment: @AlessandroChitolina Not working :(

Comment: I read that you're now behind a load balancer. Has the `X-Forwarded-For` headers been passed to nginx and forwarded to php? Have you set the trusted proxies in your index.php? You need to add all your internal netrworks' cidr.

Comment: Try to add into your `security.yml` in access_control requires_channel to https : ```access_control:
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }``` (change the role if necessary)